# Laplace transform identity: $\mathcal{L}[f^{(n)}(t)/t^m](s)=?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to know this for a specific problem I am trying to solve, and most Googling points me in the direction that there is no hope to finding such a general identity.

I know there is a formula for the Laplace transform of the $n$th derivative of a function. I also know $t^p$ has a Laplace transform. So, naturally, I wonder if $t^{-m}f^{(n)}(t)$ has a Laplace transform.

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform doesn't give one. Problem is, integration-by-parts isn't going to help you simplify anything, because you've got three terms inside the integral.

Comment: The integral you’re referring to is from the definition of a Laplace transform, namely $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{t^m}dt$, correct? I don’t know much about CASs (I assume Wolfram Dev Platform is a CAS); is Wolfram Dev Platform the most reputable CAS available?

Comment: Have you looked into the convolution theorem?

Comment: Dividing by $t$ transforms to integration.  So, you get repeated integration of the transform of a derivative. This is pretty straightforward.  The final closed form may have a lot of symbology in it, but it's not very complicated.  If you assume the boundary conditions are very zero ( eg. lots of zero derivatives ) then it simplifies a bit.  But I think the point is that the the laplace transform of $t^{-m}f^{(n)}(t)$ is not very complicated, even if it involves a lot of symbology.

Comment: Mr. McGovern: I am not knowledgable on convolutions. I can learn (eventually). What did you have in mind, though? Callus: I don’t know how you came to the conclusion that having, for example, $1/t$ in the function results in integration. So, I do not understand the bulk of your comment. Can you clarify? Are you suggesting that $\int e^{-st}\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{t^m}dt$ is easily calculated?

Comment: @000: The Wolfram Dev Platform allows you to execute Mathematica code, subject to server time constraints on the calculations. I would not hesitate to affirm that Mathematica is the best CAS in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I'm giving you an answer you're looking for, but I just noticed that you replied to me in the comments and I never got back to you.  Here's what I was getting at.

One of the properties of the Laplace transform is that if $F(s)=\mathcal{L}(f(t))$, then 
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{f(t)}{t}\right) = \int_s^\infty F(u)du
$$
Also, 
$$
\mathcal{L}\left( f^{(n)}(t) \right) = s^nF(s)-\sum_{i=1}^ns^{n-i}f^{(i-1)}(0) 
$$
So 
$
\mathcal{L}\left(t^{-m}f^{(n)}(t)\right)
$ 
can be written in terms of repeated integrals.  If $f^{(i)}(0)=0$ for all $i$, then this becomes a lot simpler.  So, in my unintentionally snarky comment, I was trying to say that the expression for the laplace transform of $t^{-m}f^{(n)}(t)$ is going to be a bunch of repeated integrations of polynomials times the laplace transform of $f$.  I shouldn't say it's not complicated, but the difficulty in evaluation is not much more difficult than repeated integrals of the transform of $f$ ( which can of course, be very complicated ).

Comment: Thank you, Callus. I had worked on this for a while, and I came to the same conclusion. I haven't investigated it further since then, but your answer is equivalent to what I figured.